# What are the ways to unwrap HTTPS in proxy-like way using standard tools?

Tags: proxy, https

For the low-end 8bit devices like home computers of 80ies, when attached to internet via newly-made network cards, or for low-end embedded devices as well, it is practically impossible to browse through https-only sites (the sites that unconditionally redirect to https:// even when http:// is explicitly specified in URL). The sole connection establishing could last for minutes, if not hours.

One possible way to overcome that is to use proxy that would unwrap HTTPS connection and present pure HTTP for the client. The client would connect to the proxying server via http-proxy or socks5 protocol and would work transparently with https sites, not even knowing they are https.

So the question is, what standard tools (like, maybe, squid) are capable of doing exactly that?

Comment: I've briefly looked at mitmproxy docs and haven't found an option to do like that. Maybe you have some insight what to look for?

Comment: Sorry. Re-reading, I had misunderstood your question. I would imagine that Apache running as a proxy could address your needs (particularly as it can do limited in-page rewriting of URLs).